# Скажите как у меня textarea в Chrome выглядит как надо, а Firefox нет

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

```css
.form__title{
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.form-input{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.input{
  width: 310px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

#textarea{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

.form__btn{
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: rgb(39, 110, 241);
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 15px 43px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 38px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class='form-input'>
    <input type="text" class='input' placeholder='Name'>
    <input type="text" class='input' placeholder='E-mail'>
    <input type="text" class='input' placeholder='Phone'>
    <textarea  type="text" name="#" id="textarea" rows='2' cols='40' placeholder='Comment' class='textarea'></textarea>
    <button class="form__btn">
        Book an appointment
    </button>
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Скажите как у меня textarea в Chrome выглядит как надо, а Firefox нет

Chrome

[image: В Chrome]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91423/discussion-on-question-by-leks-----textarea--chrome--).

Comment: в Хроме и в Мозилле выглядит одинаково (textarea на 10 пикселей меньше инпутов по ширине). Единственная разница - из-за необстиленных бордеров в Хроме всё на 1 пиксель шире. Обновите браузеры до актуальных версий, проверьте кривые плагины.